# My cooking is of the ‘quick and simple’ variety

Tags: prepositions

> My cooking is of the ‘quick and simple’ variety. vs.

> My cooking is the ‘quick and simple’ variety.

Do we need 'of' here or can we omit it?
If we need 'of', what's the function of it?

Comment: I don't think it makes any difference what specific "main category" and type of variety you're talking about. [This usage chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+of+the+same+variety%2Cis+the+same+variety&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) shows that we're much more likely to say something ***is the same variety***, without the syntactically unnecessary ***of***. But it's essentially a stylistic choice, where I suggest including ***of*** gives slightly more recognition to the fact of there being *other* "varieties" of cooking style...

Comment: ...in which context, simply discarding the reference to "variety" completely *(My cooking is‘quick and simple’)*, gives *less* recognition to the fact of there being alternative cooking varieties.

Comment: In American English nowadays you'd be more likely to *hear* it without the **of**, as the prepositional form is in a more formal register.  But in a 20th c. pre-internet text (a magazine article, say, that was edited) you'd probably find it expressed using **of**.

Comment: @TimRonsomedevice: I'm not sure *magazines* would be a typical context where you might expect to see ***of*** included more often. But your basic point about *without the **of** ... is a **more formal** register* seems wide of the mark to me. The usage chart for "common or garden **variety**" massively favours *not* including ***of***, but check [this chart](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=is+of+the+same+genre%2Cis+the+same+genre&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20). With ***genre*** (obviously far more formal) that preference reverses!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Well, I did say "*edited* magazine". There were a greater number of magazines back in the day where articles had to undergo copy editing. The chart for **genre** conforms with expectation. More formal contexts (which"genre" pretty much guarantees) use **of**.

Comment: I think I misunderstood you. Apparently you're assuming "magazines" are *informal*, but I came at this from the perspective of *anything* except actual reported speech being "formal". Tbh, even OP's ‘quick and simple’ sounds a bit "careful" to me compared to the version I'm accustomed to ('quick and **dirty**', which to me is common as muck in casual speech, but rarely turns up at all in printed material without 'scare quotes' :)